# Do all developers require access to private cocoapod repo (not private podspec)?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management

While creating a private pod, we need to create two repo. One for storing the podspec and other where our actual sharable code stays. Does a developer need to have access to both of the repositories.
If not, how is someone with no access to my private repository able to use the pod?

Answer (score 0):

Podspecs are usually in the same repo for source distributions, but they don't have to be. Either way, the pod clients need access to both.

For binary distributions, the binary needs to be accessible but the code can bee anywhere.

More details in https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html